# Evaluate a piece of ex source code

Tags: vim

If I have a multiline piece of vimscript e.g., in the clipboard,
how can I evaluate it?

Is there a way to do it other than by saving it and sourcing the saved file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose you have a file like this:

```
hello
world
foo
bar
1,4s/^/#/
```

You're on the last line, in **NORMAL** mode:

- type <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>y</kbd> to copy
- type <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>@</kbd><kbd>"</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> to run

The result is:

```
#hello
#world
#foo
#bar
1,4s/^/#/
```

You can even copy multi-line vim script to any register, then evaluate them.

Answer (score 2):

I have these two mappings in my vimrc:

```
" Source
vnoremap <leader>so y:execute @@<cr>:echo 'selection Sourced .'<cr>
nnoremap <leader>so ^vg_y:execute @@<cr>:echo 'line Sourced.'<cr>
```

which allow you press `<leader>so` to source (execute) visual selection or current line (in normal mode)

https://github.com/sk1418/myConf/blob/master/common/.vimrc#L155